How do I set up a freeable cache in Golang (i.e. I can free the memory when memory pressure is detected)?
I'm writing an application in golang. It generates a data structure in memory for a database entry upon request. Often when an entry is requested, it is requested multiple times, so I want to cache the entry in memory, to avoid multiple calls to the database (mostly for latency reasons).
Is it possible to have this in-memory cache expand dynamically in memory until we hit memory pressure (i.e. failed malloc) and then free some of the cache?
Caching in Redis or similar would complicate deployment. If that's the only other option, I'd prefer just to specify a static cache-size at run-time.
I'm not opposed to using C.malloc I suppose, but I don't know how that interacts with the Go memory management (if I allocate a chunk of memory, and then the go runtime allocates a chunk for a goroutine stack or something on top of the heap, then I can't release my memory to the OS until whatever's on top is freed). Also, I'm compiling without cgo so far, and it'd be nice to continue to do so.
I'm hoping there's something in the debug or runtime package that might hint that the system is under memory pressure so that I can dynamically size my cache and keep the program in pure Go.
Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Have you considered or even tried sync.Pool? If not: Why not? If yes: What prevents using a sync.Pool?

@Volker How would you go about using sync.Pool as an in memory cache? My understanding is that sync.Pool could be used to keep a list of allocated structs of the type you need, so you don't have to alloc memory constantly. But it doesn't (seem to) have a "Get the specific instance of the struct that has the data I need" mechanism.

Oh, sorry, you are right of course.

you might try a ring-buffer like this https://github.com/smallnest/ringbuffer

@Volker So I hadn't heard of sync.Pool, thanks for telling me about it. It would be an odd fit, but maybe possible. If I allocated several blocks of memory and added their pointers to the pool. Since I'd get a random pointer back each time, I would get a lot of cache misses, but it is nice that the GC will free those as needed. Probably wouldn't be my go-to for this problem. But I'm glad you made me aware of this so I can use it for worker threads or DB connections, which would be a great boon.

@code_monk I love me a good ringbuffer. Though, it doesn't look like it can expand dynamically and shrink in response to memory pressure.

This answer has a solution to getting memory allocation at runtime.
Here's a starting point for a concurrent-safe cache using that code:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

type Memory struct {
    MemTotal     int
    MemFree      int
    MemAvailable int
}

type Cache[T any] struct {
    MinMemFree int // Min number of free bytes
    chunkSize  int // Number of key/value pairs removed from data when MinMemFree is reached
    mu         sync.Mutex
    data       map[string]T
    order      []string // Keeps track of the order of keys added to data
}

func NewCache[T any](minMemFree int, chunkSize int) *Cache[T] {
    return &Cache[T]{
        MinMemFree: minMemFree,
        chunkSize:  chunkSize,
        data:       make(map[string]T),
        order:      []string{},
    }
}

func (c *Cache[T]) Get(key string) T {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()

    return c.data[key]
}

func (c *Cache[T]) Set(key string, value T) int {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()

    c.data[key] = value
    c.order = append(c.order, key)

    if c.minSizeReached() {
        return c.freeOldestChunk()
    }
    return 0
}

// Free oldest items in the cache, and return the number removed
func (c *Cache[T]) freeOldestChunk() int {
    count := 0
    for i := 1; i <= c.chunkSize; i++ {
        key := c.shiftOrder()
        if key == "" {
            break
        }
        delete(c.data, key)
        count++
    }
    return count
}

func (c *Cache[T]) shiftOrder() string {
    if len(c.order) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    key := c.order[0]
    c.order = c.order[1:]
    return key
}

func (c *Cache[T]) minSizeReached() bool {
    return ReadMemoryStats().MemFree <= c.MinMemFree
}

func ReadMemoryStats() Memory {
    file, err := os.Open("/proc/meminfo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    res := Memory{}
    for scanner.Scan() {
        key, value := parseLine(scanner.Text())
        switch key {
        case "MemTotal":
            res.MemTotal = value
        case "MemFree":
            res.MemFree = value
        case "MemAvailable":
            res.MemAvailable = value
        }
    }
    return res
}

func parseLine(raw string) (key string, value int) {
    text := strings.ReplaceAll(raw[:len(raw)-2], " ", "")
    keyValue := strings.Split(text, ":")
    return keyValue[0], toInt(keyValue[1])
}

func toInt(raw string) int {
    if raw == "" {
        return 0
    }
    res, err := strconv.Atoi(raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return res
}


Awesome. I think this is a workable solution. Thank you.

No problem. I'm looking for a job if you know anyone who's hiring.

I feel you, it's a crappy time in the industry right now. We're downsizing around my parts, but I wish you luck.

One easy option would be to use groupcache. While its intended goal is to provide a in memory cache that is shared by an application cluster, it can work stand alone just fine.
The following code setups up a groupcache cache, without any peers (so only your own instance of your application) with one "group" of items, limited to 64mb of memory. Once that limit is reached, the internal LRU cache will evict an item.
func main() {
    maxCacheSize := int64(64 << 20)
    items := groupcache.NewGroup("your-items", maxCacheSize, groupcache.GetterFunc(func(ctx groupcache.Context, key string, dest groupcache.Sink) error {
        // Do something expensive
        result, err := doExpensiveThing(key)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return dest.SetBytes(result)
    }))

    ctx := context.Background()
    var data string
    err := items.Get(ctx, "your-item-key", groupcache.StringSink(&data))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

Since groupcache is intended to basically cache "blobs" and distribute them across a cluster, its "sinks" (the structure you push your data into) can only operate on strings, byte slices and protobuf messages. So if you want to cache some database results you'll need to serialize it to something like JSON.
If you would want to cache different "types of things", each with their own amount of maximum memory, you can create multiple groups.
Another tradeoff is that it is not possible to delete items, not can you set an expiry. If you require either of those, groupcache probably isn't for you.

This part is the rub: maxCacheSize := int64(64 << 20), This is probably a better LRU cache than anything I could've whipped up, but I'm hoping to have one that can dynamically expand to fill available memory and shrink in response to memory pressure in order to coexist nicely with other processes.
